# Google Apps Script withSuccessHandler() doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm learning Apps Script and I'm getting very frustrated because I can't see what is wrong with my approach.

According to the docs, when running `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successFunc).myFunction()` from within an html file script, whatever myFunction returns should be available as a parameter for successFunc, or shouldn't it? I'm dubious now because I can't seem to make it work.

Here's my HTML:

```html
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="fn">Nombre</label>
        <input id="fn" name="fn" type="text">
        <label for="ln">Apellido/s</label>
        <input id="ln" name="ln" type="text">
        <button type="button" id="search">Buscar</button>
        <label for="found">Resultado</label>
        <input type="text" name="found" id="found" disabled>
        <button type="submit" id="setClient">Continuar</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        const fn = document.getElementById('fn').value;
        const ln = document.getElementById('ln').value;
        const search = document.getElementById('search');
        const found = document.getElementById('found');
        const setClient = document.getElementById('setClient');
        let clientId; // The ID of the client in the database;
        let data;

        search.addEventListener("click", () => {
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addClient).searchDb(fn, ln);
        });

       function addClient(data) {
         alert(data); // returns null
         if (!data || data === null) throw "No data found"; // don't care about gracefully catching this right now
         found.value = `${data.clientFn}, ${data.clientLn}`; // adds 'undefined, undefined'
         clientId = data.clientId;
         // google.script.host.close();
      }

      setClient.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        google.script.run.setClient(fn, ln, clientId);
      })


    </script>
</body>
```

As you can see, I've added an "alert" in the success handler just to keep track of `data` and even though I have tested the code *ad infinitum* and it always return a fully workable object, this seems to always show `null`.

Here's also my .gs function:

```js
function searchDb(fn, ln) {
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById("the ID of the SS, obviously").getSheets()[0];
  const dataRange = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 3).getValues();

  const lnRange = dataRange.map(r => { return r[2] });
  const fnRange = dataRange.map(r => { return r[1] });
  const idRange = dataRange.map(r => { return r[0] });

  for (let a = 0; a < lnRange.length; a++) {
    const clientLn = lnRange[a];
    const clientFn = fnRange[a];
    const clientId = idRange[a];

    if (clientLn.includes(ln) && clientFn === fn) {
      const data = {
        clientFn: clientFn,
        clientLn: clientLn,
        clientId: clientId
      }
      return data;
    }
  }
  return;
}
```

It is, indeed, a very simple program and it does return the `data` object with the appropriate data when I test it, so not sure what's going on here.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something pretty obvious, but I got to the point where I'm just banging my head against the wall...

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT**

I've edited the code because what I originally posted wasn't consistent - and the result of not reverting back completely from trying other approaches -. Still, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was not to do with `withSuccessHandler`, as I expected, but with how the data was passed on to `searchDb` because the vars `fn` and `ln` haven't changed value as far as the script is concerned when the search button is clicked. The solution is as simple as declaring those variables **after** the search button has been clicked:

```html
<script>

    const search = document.getElementById('search');
    const fullName = document.getElementById('fullName');
    const country = document.getElementById('country');
    const email = document.getElementById('email');
    const noClient = document.getElementById('noClient');
    const useClient = document.getElementById('useClient');
        
    let clientId; // The ID of the client in the database;

    search.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const fn = document.getElementById('fn').value;
      const ln = document.getElementById('ln').value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(addClient).searchDb(fn, ln);
    });

// ...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an array:

```
const data = {'clientFn': clientFn,'clientLn': clientLn,'clientId': clientId}
```

But your treating it as an array:

```
found.value = `${data[1]}, ${data[0]}`; 
clientId = data[2];
```

Try referring to them with their properties `'clientFn','clientLn','clientId'`

```
found.value = `${data['clientLn']}, ${data['clientFn']}`; 
clientId = data['clientId'];
```

Also you may want to refer to [this link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values) to insure that they are all legal types.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper. Truth is, I tried quite a few things, one of them being getting the data in the form of an array, and I was so tired when I posted this question that I didn't realise I hadn't gone back to having `data` as an object everywhere. I will edit my question to make sure it's all consistent, but the problem remains